# How to write a query(may be a recursive one) to fetch parent-child hierarchy in Postgresql 8.4?

Tags: postgresql, recursion, postgresql-8.4

I have a parent child hierarchy that is depicted as in the picture. There is one head office at the top which acts as the parent branch.  The other nodes are child branches.
There can be any number of Regional zones and any number of divisional zones can be added to a Regional zone. Similarly, any number of child branches can be added to a divisional zone. Here, User login is provided at all the levels and there I'm facing a difficulty in showing only the branches that is child to the currently logged in users branch. The data base that I'm using is 'Postgresql8.4'. By Googling I found that `recursion` can be done. But quite frankly I didn't understand the steps followed in most of them. So can someone please help me in solving this piece of puzzle with explanation on the steps followed?

[image]

```
User Table
============
usr_id;     //Unique id of user
usr_branch_id;  //Id from the branch table


Branch Table
============
branch_id;  //Unique id of branch
branch_text_id;
branch_name;
branch_parent;
```

Comment: Explanation and examples in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html

Comment: @DanielVérité Thanks for posting. The main reason behind this post was that I didn't get a clear cut idea from such documents to take this thing to an implementation level.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL: Loop Until a Condition is True](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840449/postgresql-loop-until-a-condition-is-true)

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for commenting. Hope you have read my previous comment. I saw the link and I think it may have the answer. Would you please care to explain the steps. I hope I have made it very clear in my question.

Comment: [My answer to that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11840910/479863) has a pretty simple example of WITH RECURSIVE. Have you tried to map that to your tables? What happened when you did?

Comment: @muistooshort What is the point in implementation with out understanding the concept correctly? Most of the answers that I saw is pretty much similar to the one that you have posted. But, how does it work? In that answer there is a where clause `where id = 4` and 4 is the nth row. Here I can't say what id will be the id of the nth row. Moreover its bottom up parsing as far as I understood,not the kind of scenario that I'm looking for. And one more thing that I've noted is you have edited that answer a little bit just now. `UNION` was changed to `UNION ALL`. Why was that done so?

Comment: So you're looking for an explanation of WITH RECURSIVE? I changed the UNION to UNION ALL because the plain UNION was a typo (that wouldn't change the result of the query, it would just make it waste a bit of time). Have you tried getting your hands dirty with a WITH RECURSIVE query to get a feel for how it works?

Comment: @muistooshort yes.I've mapped it and its working as intended. So would you care to explain how recursion works.?

Comment: I'm having a hard time coming up with a simple explanation. The key is that you have a `recursive` CTE called `R` and then inside `R`, you join your table to `R` so the CTE is sort of self-referential: `with recursive R as (select ... union all select ... from T join R ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

you would want something like:

```
 WITH RECURSIVE branch_tree AS (
         select branch_id, branch_text_id, branch_name, branch_parent, 
                branch_id::text as path
           from branch
          where branch_parent is null
      union all
         select b.branch_id, b.branc_text_id, b.branch_name, b.branch_parent, 
                t.path || ',' || b.branch_id::text 
           FROM branch b
           JOIN branch_tree t ON b.parent_id = t.branch_id
 )
 SELECT * FROM branch_tree ORDER BY string_to_array(path, ',')::int[];
```